# How to prevent auto formatting after moving files to another package in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin

Whenever I try to move file to another package, Android Studio reformats file's code structure to a different state.

For example such part of code:

```
doSomething(makeSomeParameters(value1, value))
```

becomes:

```
doSomething(
    makeSomeParamaters(
        value1,
        value2
    )
)
```

Notice that this line was not exceeding 100 columns constraint.

I use code style from official [Kotlin style guide](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html).

> To configure the IntelliJ formatter according to this style guide,
>   please install Kotlin plugin version 1.2.20 or newer, go to Settings |
>   Editor | Code Style | Kotlin, click on "Set from…" link in the upper
>   right corner, and select "Predefined style / Kotlin style guide" from
>   the menu.

Comment: `// @formatter:off` (with a corresponding one at the end with `on` instead of `off`) might prevent the formatter from doing that - but you might have to enable it in settings first.

Comment: Could you point out where should I change it in settings and what it implies?

Comment: The comment itself is self-explanatory - it toggles the formatter. You place the `off` at the start of the block you don't want auto-formatted, and re-enable it at the end. This can be a single line, an entire function, or more for that matter. The setting is in file -> settings -> editor -> code style under the "formatter control" tab - and yes, you do need to enable it. You can also customize it as you'd like, so you're actually not required to use the `@formatter:[on/off]` pattern if you prefer something else.

Comment: I should probably specify that's manual enabling and disabling - it will unfortunately not fix the issue automatically. It could also be a bug in the formatter

Comment: Such line in every file would look horrible...

Comment: Like I said, not efficient or pretty, but it does the trick. If this is a bug, you should consider also reporting it to the JetBrains issue tracker

Comment: Ok, thanks for idea!

Answer (score 0):

When you attempt to move a file to another package and Android Studio shows this dialog:

[image]

Uncheck the **Update package directive** check box; Android Studio will not reformat the code in the file.